# pandas read_csv set `dtype` by column index (not name)

Tags: python, pandas, types

`file.txt` has a header and four columns. But the headers changes all the time.

something like:

```
,'non_standard_header_1','non_standard_header_2','non_standard_header_3'
,kdfjlkjdf, sdfdfd,,
,kdfjlkjwwdf, sdfddffd,,
,kdfjlkjwwdf,, sdfddffd,
```

I want to import `file.txt` in pandas, and I want the columns to be import as a `object`. The intuitive approach (to me):

`dtype        = [object, object, object]` as in:

```
    daily_file              = pandas.read_csv('file.txt',
                                              usecols      = [1, 2, 3],
                                              dtype        = [object, object, object])
```

does not work, running the above, I get:

`data type not understood`

How to set column `dtype` on import w/o referencing (existing) column names?

Comment: Experimentally, i found a way to handle this. Given a CSV with a single unlabeled column (the first one, created by `pandas.to_csv` without specifying a label for the index), Pandas assigned the name "Unnamed: 0" to that column; I was able to use that same string as a dict key for `dtype` and correctly control the datatype for the column.  Not sure how general this is, so leaving that and a proper "answer" to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.read_csv(..., dtype=object)` will globally apply the object dtype across all columns read in, if that's what you're looking for.

Otherwise, you'll need to pass a dict of the form `{'col' : dtype}` if you want to map dtypes to column names.

Comment: Almost: how do you map dtypes to colunm *numbers*?

Comment: @user189035 Try changing the keys to the index. But if that doesn't work, then I'm afraid pandas has no support for it (yet).

Comment: Indices seem to work for `dtype`, (`use_cols` has that functionality to reference either by name or index) Not sure what would happen if you had a column name overlap an index though.